# Topological features of a boundary of a contractible manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

I'm new to low dimensional topology, so I have a question. Suppose I have a 4-dimensional manifold $M$ with boundary, and I know that $M$ is contractible, so my question is: can I find some information about its boundary?

Especially, I'm interested in homology and homotopy groups of boundary.

Comment: What did you try? What algebraic topology tools do you know?

Comment: Ok,i know homology ,cohomology groups as well,also i know characteristic classes. So my main problem is to understand when seifert homological sphere bounds contractible manifold , so i want some criteria which maybe will depend on Rokhlin invariant and Kasson invrariant. So my idea is to understand topological properties of boundary of smooth contractible 4 manifolds to understand at first which Seifert spheres cannot bound contractible manifold

Comment: Do you know Poincare Duality? If you do, what can you say about homology groups of the boundary in this situation?

Comment: So we have boundary of a M is W is a 3 manifold which is oriented and without boundary,so we know that $H_3(W)=\mathbb{Z}$ so the generator depends on choose of orientation on W, then lets use poincare duality and write $H_i(W)=H^{n-i}(W)$,where n = 3

Comment: And another question arrises:if i use (M,W) as a topological pair , a can write long exact sequence of homotopy groups: $...\rightarrow\pi_2(M)\rightarrow\pi_2(M,W)\rightarrow \pi_1(W)\rightarrow\pi_1(M) $ due to contractability of M i can assume that $\pi_2(M,W)= \pi_1(M)$,so fundamental group of M is abelian,am I right?